# Need a small & simple embedded db in java: SQLJet vs. JavaDB/Apache Derby

Tags: java, sql, database, derby

I have an application running with a MySQL database. But this MySQL database is currently to fat and to uncomfortable. I only need a database on a file share and the application also on the file share so that every user can run the application with the database from the file share.

There are max. 12 users in a 100 Mbit/s network working with only text data and numbers (I think the traffic per user per day might be 1-5 MB) on a samba share.

My first idea was to use [SQLJet](http://sqljet.com/) for this job. The description is nice and it supports multi-user access. And my tests are good. But on an other page was written that running SQLite on file shares with ["[...] it might be possible for two or more client programs to modify the same part of the same database at the same time, resulting in database corruption."](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html). And that aren't good news for a stable application ...

Then I thought about JavaDB (aka. Apache Derby). I think this is a powerfull tool with a long history and some importance from Sun (which supports JavaDB since JDK 1.5). But I don't know if JavaDB supports multi-user access from scratch and how this works ...

So I want to ask you if you could suggest me a simple & small embedded database system for java which supports muli-user access on a file share or to rate my possabilites or to tell me your experiences with JavaDB or SQLJet!

Greetings from Germany,
mythbu

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at H2. It's the best pure-java embedded database I know, very featured and fast:

http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html

But I don't really understand your problem with MySQL, can you explain more ?

Comment: So MySQL is a good DBMS if you think about big applications or web environments. But for my current project I need only a database as storage. The user permissions are very easy: every user can do everything and the admin cann add users. And I am operating with MySQL users (because of the fact, that my Java application connects directly via JDBC to the database) and this is very bad for simple environments as described. Also is it very difficult to backup the MySQL database for my specific case. So a database file on a file share with application which modifies it is easyer to do for me.

Answer (score 0):

Derby indeed supports multi-user access; the simplest way is to use the Network Server, documented here: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/adminguide/cadminov825266.html

If you want to embed Derby in your application, yet still allow multiple users to access the database, things can get slightly more complicated, but they are still possible. You need to describe your intended architecture more clearly in order to discuss those issues more fully.